# log4j: Bubble up error/exception details

Tags: java, logging, log4j, error-logging, mdc

My team is using slf4j for logging purposes and are looking at logging errors/exception situations at the top of the hierarchy in the class (For ex: Class A-> Class B-> Class C(exception here) === log in Class A method).

It'd be good if we could bubble up some specific details from the bottom-most class to the top so as to avoid any loss in information. (At many places we are translating one exception to other, in such a case we'll have no clue of what happened where?)

Is there a way to do so in log4j besides using MDC?

Comment: Why to translate exceptions? just throw Exception or Throwable and catch it at level you want.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is how can I bubble up the status?